# click item in list -> view details but no output? Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

sorry for another post, still learning. 
Please help with the problem.
Also would be happy if someone could explain their answers too. Thanks!

The items show up in a list format with the html code below.

```
<div class="post row" ng-repeat="(postId, post) in posts">
   <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
```

But when I put the same code without the ng-repeat into the details page, it has no output.

Below are the outputs for the 2 differennt scenarios:

1)If i use `ng-click="view(postId)"`, with a more complicated ui-state, with view defined;

```
$scope.view = function(postId) {
      $state.go('tab.posts.view', {postId: postId});
    };,
```

**it displays ()**

2) If I use `ui-sref="tab.view({postId:post.id})"`, with a simpler ui-router state;

**it displays {{post.title}}**

**But both are bad output!**

Update: F12 error

> Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "". Paths
>   must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Answer (score 1):

try this because post !== Post

```
$scope.post = Post.find($stateParams.postId);
```